# How to query on Firestore sub collection and get spacyfyi document id?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Please read carefully what I want. Here is my Firestore database structure:
[Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYxxf.png)

I want to start a query to find user-entered refer code is available / not in the Firestore database. All available refer codes of my users are stored in [collection]users--->[uid/Document Id]--->[Field]myRefer.

In my app user can create an account with a referral code I want to check if entered refer code is available in the database, I want to show the document id where is available the referral code. I want to show the document id in a text view.

Please help me with the Java language in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if entered refer code is available in the database

To be able to check if for example, `@e0f2f67` exists in the "users" collection or not, please use the following lines of code:

```
String myRefer = "@e0f2f67";

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query queryByMyRefer = db.collection("users").whereEqual("myRefer", myRefer);
queryByMyRefer.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String name = document.getString("name");
                    Log.d(TAG, name + " already exists");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, name + " does not exists");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

In which `myRefer` is defined as in the screenshot, so we can make the comparison.

Comment: Hey. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?